# Write array to xml file

Tags: php, xml, arrays

```
//this is the code that creates the array and the output follows
while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $returned_results[]= array(
                                    'partName'=>$results_row['partName'],
                                    'description'=>$results_row['description'],
                                    'price'=>$results_row['price']

//what is contained in the array is as follows
Array
(
[partName] => Cooler Master CM Storm Trooper Case
[description] => Armored appearance. Nicely placed handle at the top. At the front; ext
[price] => 36000
)
1

Array
(
[partName] => Cooler Master eXtreme Power Plus 500-Watt
[description] => Power Plus 500-Watt Power Supply,many SATA and peripheral connectors. 
[price] => 23000
)
1

Array
(
[partName] => Coolmax M-500B ATX Power Supply
[description] => The Coolmax M-500B ATX Power Supply has 5 SATA and 5 Peripheral, 8 pin
[price] => 20000
)
```

**I need to write the data contained in the array variable($returned_results[]) to an xml file. After that i will display it in an xml table. But i think i can manage the latter. Could you help me with a code example. Please & Thank you!!**

the xml file should conatin the array data that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <results>
           <partName>Cooler Master CM Storm Trooper Case</partName>
           <description>Armored appearance. Nicely placed handle at the top. At the front; ext... </description>
           <price>36000</price>
     </results>
     <results>
            <partName>Cooler Master eXtreme Power Plus 500-Watt</partName>
            <description>Power Plus 500-Watt Power Supply,many SATA and peripheral connectors. ... </description>
             <price>23000</price>
    </results
    <results>
            <partName>Coolmax M-500B ATX Power Supply </partName>
            <description>The Coolmax M-500B ATX Power Supply has 5 SATA and 5 Peripheral, 8 pin..</description>
             <price>20000</price>
    </results>
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/155197)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use PHP itself (rather than `echo` or `fwrite`, etc.) to write your XML.

```
ob_start();
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?php
while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
?>
<results>
    <partName><?php echo htmlspecialchars($results_row['partName']);?></partName>
</results>
<?php
}

file_put_contents('file.xml', ob_get_clean());
```

Comment: O.K, Well I'm getting an error message on the <results> tag. Its telling me that Element "results" not allowed as a child element body in this context. How do i resolve this

Comment: That's a problem outside of the PHP realm :)

Comment: That's because there can be only one root node...here all `<results>` nodes are appended to the root.

Answer (score 0):

Use fwrite(). Ex:

```
$filecontents = file_get_contents ("file.xml");
$file = fopen(file.xml, w+);
//If you uncomment the next line, it will keep the current contents, if not it will overwrite it
//fwrite($file, $filecontents);
fwrite($file, $string/array-to-write);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: I'm sorry if i wasn't clear. It's more about writing it to the file with a particular format that i have specified above..

Comment: Yes, Could you give me an example.

Comment: [foreach php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) This is pretty self-explanitory.

Comment: ex `foreach ($something as $something) {$code="<result><partNum>$something</partNum></result>"; fwrite($file, $code);}

Comment: I really don't understand don't you have any code similar to what i want. How does using the loop give me the XML formatted output.

Comment: for each variable in the array it will write `<result><partNum>$something</partNum></result>` - you can also add the other variables